# Create new value in legend for 2nd and 3rd drilldown

Tags: highcharts, legend, drilldown

I have create graph 3 level drilldown and want to show legend of 3rd level follow with color.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
        rotation: -45,
        align: "right",
        y: 30,
      },
      type: "category",
      tickWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: true,
      itemStyle: {
        fontSize:'10px'
      },
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      layout: 'vertical',
      reversed:true

    },
    plotOptions: {
       
      series: {
        cropThreshold: 1000,
        animation: {
          duration: 300
        },
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
          events: {
            click: function () {
              if(this.id)
              {
                alert(this.id);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      column: {
        cropThreshold: 1000,
        minPointLength: 3,
        animation: false,
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
    },
    series: [{
              index: 0,
              name: 'Tippers',
              turboThreshold: 0,
              cropThreshold: Infinity,
              data: [{
                        name:'01-Feb-2018',
                        colorByPoint:true,
                        y:3,
                        drilldown:'Tippers-1-2-2018'
                      }]
            }],
     drilldown: {
       activeAxisLabelStyle: {
                textDecoration: 'none',
                color: 'black',
                fontWeight: 'normal'
              },
              series: [{
                          name: '01-Feb-2018',
                          id: 'Tippers-1-2-2018',
                          turboThreshold: 0,
                          cropThreshold: Infinity,
                          showInLegend: false,
                          data: [ {
                                    name: 'psb04221',
                                    y: 1,
                                    drilldown:'psb04221/Tippers-1-2-2018'
                                    },{
                                    name: 'rvd910939',
                                    y: 2,
                                    drilldown:'rvd910939/Tippers-1-2-2018'
                                    },]
                      },{
                          name: '01-Feb-2018',
                          id: 'Trucks-1-2-2018',
                          turboThreshold: 0,
                          cropThreshold: Infinity,
                          showInLegend: false,
                          data: [ {
                                    name: 'rvd910939',
                                    y: 2,
                                    drilldown:'rvd910939/Trucks-1-2-2018'
                                    },{
                                    name: 'sks913031',
                                    y: 1,
                                    drilldown:'sks913031/Trucks-1-2-2018'
                                    },]
                      },{
                          name: 'psb04221 / Tippers 1-February-2018',
                          id: 'psb04221/Tippers-1-2-2018',
                          turboThreshold: 0,
                          cropThreshold: Infinity,
                          showInLegend: false,
                          data: [ {
                            name: '01-February-2018-44',
                            id: '44',
                            y: 1,
                            type_legend: 'green',
                            color:'green'
                         
                          },]
                        },{
                          name: 'rvd910939 / Tippers 1-February-2018',
                          id: 'rvd910939/Tippers-1-2-2018',
                          turboThreshold: 0,
                          cropThreshold: Infinity,
                          showInLegend: false,
                          data: [ {
                            name: '01-February-2018-21',
                            id: '21',
                            y: 1,
                            type_legend: 'green',
              color:'green'
                          },{
                            name: '01-February-2018-25',
                            id: '25',
                            y: 1,
                            type_legend: 'yellow',
                            color:'yellow'
                          },{
                            name: '01-February-2018-27',
                            id: '27',
                            y: 1,
                            type_legend: 'green',
              color:'green'
                         
                          },]
                        },{
                          name: 'rvd910939 / Trucks 1-February-2018',
                          id: 'rvd910939/Trucks-1-2-2018',
                          turboThreshold: 0,
                          cropThreshold: Infinity,
                          showInLegend: false,
                          data: [ {
                            name: '01-February-2018-13',
                            id: '13',
                            y: 1,
                            type_legend: 'red',
                            color:'red'
                          },{
                            name: '01-February-2018-26',
                            id: '26',
                            y: 1,
                            type_legend: 'green',
                            color:'green'
                          },]
                        },{
                          name: 'sks913031 / Trucks 1-February-2018',
                          id: 'sks913031/Trucks-1-2-2018',
                          turboThreshold: 0,
                          cropThreshold: Infinity,
                          showInLegend: false,
                          data: [ {
                            name: '01-February-2018-22',
                            id: '22',
                            y: 1,
                            type_legend: 'yellow',
                            color:'yellow'
                          },{
                            name: '01-February-2018-23',
                            id: '23',
                            y: 1,
                            type_legend: 'green',
                            color:'green'
                          },]
                        }]
       }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

1st drilldown legend show date is correct

2nd drilldown I want to show legend users

3rd drilldown I want to show legend for color filter

Please help me to add legend for show legend filter by color Red , Green and Blue of 3rd drilldown like this image : [3rd Drilldown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3sN8.jpg)

Comment: Please follow link for jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0zr6ok59/22/

Comment: update drilldown series `showInLegend: true,` check demo http://jsfiddle.net/bhoae30t/

Comment: @Deep 3015 , Not correct for my question, I want to filter by color red, blue and green only

Comment: I want 3rd drilldown show legend like this image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3sN8.jpg

Comment: I see that you posted that subject on Highcharts forum too: https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/change-type-of-value-in-legend-of-3rd-drilldown-t40414/ Let the discussion to be continued there.

Comment: @Kamil Kulig ok, Let's go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved problem by answer of ppotaczek.

---

In your example, the third level of drilldown is one series, that is why the legend show only one item. If you want to have multiple legend items on drilldown, you have to have multiple series. You can use drilldown event and addSeriesAsDrilldown method, like in the example below to achieve needed result.

Live demo: `http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/amg8234t/`

API Reference:

```
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeriesAsDrilldown

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drilldown
```

Best regards!

Thank you so much.